# Create or Update Roles in Apache Superset Programmatically

Tags: apache-superset

Is there any way by which we can create new roles programmatically in Superset? I have checked the docs but can't find any hooks to create the roles programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

Superset is using Flask App Builder which has which also has CRUD REST api for security models.

What you need to do is to enable API during initialisation of app, to achieve that you need to modify `superset_config.py`

Let's assume that you use docker-compose file provided by Superset https://github.com/apache/superset/tree/master/docker

in `pythonpath_dev` directory create `custom_initializer.py` file

`custom_initializer.py` code:

```py
from superset.app import SupersetAppInitializer
from superset.extensions import appbuilder
from superset.security import SupersetSecurityManager


class MySupsersetAppInitializer(SupersetAppInitializer):
    def init_views(self) -> None:
        # Adds api for roles
        appbuilder.add_api(SupersetSecurityManager.role_api)

        # Uncomment if you want as well to add api for permissions, users, ect.

        # appbuilder.add_api(SupersetSecurityManager.permission_api)
        # appbuilder.add_api(SupersetSecurityManager.user_api)
        # appbuilder.add_api(SupersetSecurityManager.view_menu_api)
        # appbuilder.add_api(SupersetSecurityManager.permission_view_menu_api)

        super().init_views()
```

Now modify `superset_config.py`. Add those lines:

```
from custom_initializer import MySupsersetAppInitializer

APP_INITIALIZER = MySupsersetAppInitializer
```

Now you should be able to have access to API implemented by Flask App Builder

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to the previous answers would be to enable the FAB REST API in Superset. Apache Superset uses [Flask App Builder](https://github.com/dpgaspar/Flask-AppBuilder) (FAB), whose API is hidden by default.

Setting [FAB's configuration variable](https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) `FAB_ADD_SECURITY_API = True` in `superset_config.py` adds a CRUD REST API for users, roles, permissions, view_menus reachable under `/api/v1/security`. [More on how to configure Apache Superset](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset).

- Add a new role (without permissions):

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/roles/ \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'X-CSRFToken: token' \
  --data '{"name": "my_new_role"}'
```

This creates the role "my_new_role" with `id=6`.

- Add permission to role:

```bash
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/roles/6/permissions \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'X-CSRFToken: token' \
  --data '{"permission_view_menu_ids": [1,2]}'
```

This adds the permissions with `id=1` and `id=2` to the role with `id=6`.

Here is an example to do the same with Python:

```py
import requests

base_url = 'http://localhost:8088/api/v1'

def get_bearer_token():
    payload = {
        "password": "admin",
        "provider": "db",
        "username": "admin"
    }
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
    response = requests.request("POST", f"{base_url}/security/login", json=payload, headers=headers)
    return response.json()["access_token"]

def get_csrf_token():
    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {get_bearer_token()}"}
    response = requests.request("GET", f"{base_url}/security/csrf_token/", data="", headers=headers)
    return response.json()["result"]

def add_role(name):
    headers = {
        'X-CSRFToken': get_csrf_token(),
        'Authorization': f"Bearer {get_bearer_token()}"
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", f"{base_url}/security/roles", json={"name": name}, headers=headers)
    return response.json()

def add_permissions_to_role(role_id, permissions):
    headers = {
        'X-CSRFToken': get_csrf_token(),
        'Authorization': f"Bearer {get_bearer_token()}"
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", f"{base_url}/security/roles/{role_id}/permissions", json={"permission_view_menu_ids": permissions}, headers=headers)
    return response.json()

add_role("my_new_role")
add_permissions_to_role(6, [1,2])
```

Comment: Without doing the steps mentioned in this ans I was getting an API not found error, after doing this I got 403 FORBIDDEN error. It worked only after doing the steps mentioned in puchal's ans.

Comment: How did you get the id = 6?

Comment: @IamAshay `GET` on `/api/v1/security/roles`. There you will see all your roles and ids.

Answer (score 2):

I use Superset as a python library, and got the same problem a few months ago...

first you have to create a Custom Security Manager... to do this i read  this tutorial https://programmer.group/tutorial-how-to-integrate-superset-in-your-own-application.html

Essentially you make the call from your superset_config.py file like this

```
from core_utils.security import CustomSecurityManager

CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSecurityManager
```

In the **init** method of the CustomSecurityManager() you can make the call to add_role() function... this do the trick

--

- SupersetSecurityManager is the object that have available functions to manage user programatically
- Sorry for my bad english, this is my first collaboration, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but more details like in puchal's answer would have been helpful.